# HTML tags remove from textarea using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I remove HTML tags when pasting some copied content  and paste in a text editor.
My text editor:

```
<textarea onchange="RemoveTags(this.val)"> Enter some words </textarea>
```

Apply Javascript:

```
function RemoveTags(val){
    console.log(val);
}
```

I am not getting result.

Comment: Try `RemoveTags(this.value)`. https://jsfiddle.net/fm89bgz3/ Also, actually replacing with text - https://jsfiddle.net/753rmtpx/.

Comment: Yes, it getting value but how can remove html tags while copy paste content. Thanks.

Comment: Did you look at the second link? The one after I said "Also, actually replacing with text..."?

Answer (score 2):

Apply this code.

```
var StrippedString = OriginalString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```